# Mysql check if column in a row is contained in another column?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a mysql query that checks if a column in a row is contained within another column in the same row. Is there a way to do that kinda of query?

for example:

```
Key        Value         runHash  
2500       tacos         night.2500.293849284 
1775       windows       day.176555.43035842
```

I am trying to write a query that will return the second row and not the first because for the first row, Key is in runHash.

I tried to do:

```
select * from table where key not in runHash
```

However this doesn't appear to be valid for mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `like`:

```
where runHash like concat('%', key, '%')
```

You can put periods in the pattern as well, if those are important for your pattern matching.